# How to link label to another page?

Tags: hyperlink

How to create hyperlink from page to another page even if there is no section or chapter ? and the easy way to automatically make it color blue of all the hyperlink I created. Thank you in advance.

```
        \documentclass{article}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage{xcolor}
        \usepackage{hyperref}

        \title{Hyperlink}
        \author{For Testing }
        \date{August 2022}

        \begin{document}

        \maketitle

        \section{Introduction}
        \color{blue}{page 2\\
        page 3\\
        page 4 title name}

        Lorem

        \clearpage
        page 2

        \clearpage
        page 3

        \clearpage
        page4\\
        page 4 title name

        \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For links with arbitrary text, you can use `\hyperlink{label}{Link text}` with a matching `\hypertarget{label}{Link destination}`.

For a link to something marked with `\label`, you can use `\hyperref[label]{link text}`.

For page number links you can use `\pageref` to a label; you may need to use `\phantomsection` before the target.

If you want links to be blue, use the `colorlinks` and `linkcolor=blue` options for hyperref.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\title{Hyperlink}
\author{For Testing}
\date{August 2022}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\hyperlink{page2anchor}{Link to page 2}\\
\hyperlink{page3anchor}{Link to page 3}\\
\hyperlink{page4anchor}{Link to page 4}

\hyperref[alabelkey]{Arbitrary link to label}

That label is on page \pageref{alabelkey}

\clearpage
\hypertarget{page2anchor}{page 2}

\clearpage
\hypertarget{page3anchor}{page 3}

\clearpage
\hypertarget{page4anchor}{page 4}

\phantomsection\label{alabelkey} Here

\end{document}
```

See the [hyperref package documentation](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/hyperref-doc.pdf).